# Setup MySQL and Oracle Database Mac OS X

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, localhost

I am familiar with using MAMP but I now need to setup a MySQL and Oracle database locally of which I will need to connect to both from the same PHP file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started with this?

Comment: Do you have Oracle and MySQL installed on mac? OR you want to download also?

Comment: I now have MySQL installed and setup on my Mac. I have no idea if I have Oracle or not. I have never used it before!

Answer (score 0):

There is an old version of Oracle (10g R2) for an old version of Mac OS X (10.5). I wouldn't go there, as nothing has changed since 2005.

I installed a VirtualBox running Oracle's Database App Development VM:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

### MySQL

Get MySQL from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). Once DMG file is downloaded install it.

For step-by-step, refer [**this**](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2011/02/10/mac-os-x-mysql-install/).

---

### Oracle

Download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/macos/downloads/index.html) and for step-by-step installation refer [**this**](http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/04/12/how-to-install-oracle-database-10g-on-mac-os-x-intel/), [**this**](http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/09/14/how-to-install-oracle-database-10g-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/) and [**this**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/macos/articles/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @Fahim Parkar but the Oracle download link you gave gives this "The version of Oracle Database you are looking for is no longer available on OTN" when you go to download it.

Comment: @EdHart : See what Mr.Google says [**The version of Oracle Database you are looking for is no longer available on OTN**](https://www.google.com.kw/search?q=The+version+of+Oracle+Database+you+are+looking+for+is+no+longer+available+on+OTN&rlz=1C5CHFA_enKW503KW503&oq=The+version+of+Oracle+Database+you+are+looking+for+is+no+longer+available+on+OTN&aqs=chrome.0.57j61l2j60l2j62.240&sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Don't install Oracle locally on your system. Get [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) and install [one of the pre-built VM appliances from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) after that you can install MySQL into this VM.

It is way better because system updates will not touch your installation, you can move it to another machine. And you don't need to worry about starting up, shutting down, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Oracle Database Mac OS X

1. Make your virtual machine uses Bridge Mode not NAT for networking.
2. Download "Oracle Database 11g Express Edition" on your virtual machine OS.
3. Find the ip address of your virtual machine.
4. Download latest JDK for Mac
5. Download Oracle SQL Developer Downloads on your mac.
6. Enter informations like this:

**Connection Name**: YourConnectionName
**Password**: What you made when you install Oracle DB Express 
**Hostname**: Virtual machine ip address
**Port**: 1521
**SID**: xe

[image]